# strong-pm always display connection refused

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have installed `strong-pm` on my remote server and have successfully deployed one `strongloop` application. I can use `sl-pmctl ls` to see the service and its id is 1.

First, i tested remotely, I get an 502 error. Then I tested on the remote server using

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST  --data '{"userName":"e23213123", "password":"safdaff"}'  http://127.0.0.1:3001/`

And the terminal shows me

`curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 3001: Connection refused`

I googled several hours and cannot find any solution. It just shows me `Connection refused`, where should I start to fix it.

Comment: Did you verify the port is opened?

Comment: @ReuvenChacha no, it is not open. But the `sl-pmctl ls` already list it there. How can I known if the loopback application is running properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can monitor the process on the remote server using

```
sudo tail -f -n 200 /var/log/upstart/strong-pm.log
```

or a similar tail on that log. If nothing seems out of the ordinary and there aren't any connection errors, the service is running properly.

But if port 3001 is not allowed even from localhost, you have other config issues besides the strongloop strong-pm process.

Comment: I see the log file. and it shows me that it is lack of a library.